# Packer HCL template An argument or block definition is required here

Tags: packer

I have prepared the HCL template to automate build image however it is giving following error while executing please suggest

Here is the code:

```html
 required_plugins {
    azure = {
      version = ">= 1.0.0"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
    }
  }
}
source "azure-arm" "example" {
  managed_image_name                 = "MT-Image"
  managed_image_resource_group_name  = "cg"
  location                           = "eastus"
  # Using Azure CLI for authentication
  use_azure_cli_auth = true
  image_offer     = "visualstudio2022"
  image_publisher = "microsoftvisualstudio"
  image_sku       = "20_04-lts-gen2"
  os_type         = "Windows"
  vm_size         = "Standard_E2b_v5"
  os_disk_size_gb = 64
  shared_image_gallery_destination {
    resource_group       = "cg"
    gallery_name         = "gallery1"
    image_name           = "newimage"
    image_version        = "1.0.1"
    replication_regions  = ["eastus"]
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
}
build {
  sources = [
    "source.azure-arm.example"
  ]
  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = [
      "Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Server",
      "while ((Get-Service RdAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
      "while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
      "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit",
      "while($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error:

[image]

I have prepared the HCL template to automate build image however it is giving following error while executing please suggest

Answer (score 0):

`packer` block is missing at the beginning of the file
example:

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    azure = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
      version = "~> 2"
    }
  }
}
```